# Using Autolayout in IB how do I position a UIView in the center of the screen programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a UIView that I would like to center horizontally over the main view and then center vertically over the main view, minus about 14 pixels.

If I set it up with IB it works on the Retina 3.5, but when running on Retina 4 it is of course off by roughly 40 pixels.

I am thinking the best solution is establishing these constraints programmatically based on screen height?

Comment: How did you set this up in IB? I've done it before and it's worked well.

Comment: For kicks, I just tried it now to your exact spec center y alignment constraint with a constant of -14.

Comment: Just used the top and bottom constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the centerX and centerY constants, and put in a constant of 14 (or -14 not sure which way you want it to be),

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:14]];
```

Comment: where can I get useful reference about adding auto layout constraints via code ? thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the three videos on auto layout from the WWDC 2012?  They give a lot of info on how to use NSLayoutconstraints.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your view in Center(Horizontally & Vertically). Select the view in Interface Builder, then from Top Menu, Select Editor> Align> Horizontal Center in Container/ Vertical Center in Container.

You can also add more constraints to satisfy view's Geometry.

Comment: The OP is asking about doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set constraints programmatically to align a view to horizontal & vertical center of the screen. It can be done via Interface builder itself. However, you still can set constraints using NSLayoutAnchor apis in code, like the below example. NSLayoutAnchor apis are simple, elegant and, concise. And are available since iOS 9.

```
myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)
myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
```